# TSQL procedure that neither raises an error nor completes prescribed behaviour

Tags: azure-sql-database, dynamic-sql

#### Overview

I wrote a procedure that changes a column type and applies a unique constraint to it. The procedure executes and completes successfully, however, **neither the column type is changed nor has the unique constraint been applied**. When I `SELECT @tsql` to inspect the statements produced and run them in Azure Data Studio they work fine. Equally at no point is an error raised.

The database service I am using is **Azure SQL Database Instance**.

#### The procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_aProcName]
    @tableName NVARCHAR(250),
    @fieldName NVARCHAR(250)
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @tsql VARCHAR(MAX) = N'ALTER TABLE my_schema.'+@tableName+' ALTER COLUMN '+@fieldName+' INT NOT NULL;';
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql;
        
        SET @tsql = N'ALTER TABLE my_schema.'+@tableName+' ADD CONSTRAINT AK_'+@tableName+'_'+@fieldName+' UNIQUE ('+@fieldName+');';
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql;
        
        RETURN 0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        RETURN @@ERROR;
    END CATCH
;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can remove return 0 and check once again?

Comment: I removed the `RETURN 0;` clause and ran the procedure. Neither did the type change nor was there a constraint; behaviour is the same.

Comment: OK, I think I have seen the issue; the variable `@tsql` is `VARCHAR`, should be `NVARCHAR`. I don't understand why SQL Server is swallowing the error. I would expect the first `sp_executesql` to fail, hit the `CATCH` and return an error code.

Comment: You can use `PRINT @tsql` to see the difference of the output.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`. Note that it gets more interesting when you combine multiple strings to create the constraint name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolving the runtime error;

Dynamic SQL must be to be assigned to an `NVARCHAR`, `NCHAR` or `NTEXT` type, **not** `VARCHAR`. **The error was being caught** but not displayed in Azure Data Studio despite returning `@@ERROR` in the case of exception.

Errors are intended to be returned to the orchestration layer (Azure Data Factory) and stored in another databsae. Error handling remodelled (this is a mock);

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_aProcName]
    @tableName NVARCHAR(250),
    @fieldName NVARCHAR(250)
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN TranName;
        DECLARE @tsql VARCHAR(MAX) = N'ALTER TABLE my_schema.'+@tableName+' ALTER COLUMN '+@fieldName+' INT NOT NULL;';
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql;
        
        SET @tsql = N'ALTER TABLE my_schema.'+@tableName+' ADD CONSTRAINT AK_'+@tableName+'_'+@fieldName+' UNIQUE ('+@fieldName+');';
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql;
        
        COMMIT TRAN TranName;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN TranName;
        SELECT
            OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) AS [ProcedureName],
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ErrorMessage],
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS [ErrorNumber],
            ERROR_LINE() AS [ErrorLine],
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS [ErrorSeverity],
            ERROR_STATE() AS [ErrorState]
        ;
    END CATCH
;
```

Comment: Nope - that is not a requirement. You should since object names are defined as nvarchar (as are your parameters) but it is not a requirement. Your problem is that you caught an error but "ate it" by simply using the error code for the procedure's return value. Erland has good [error handling discussion](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)

Comment: Microsoft article on `sp_executesql ` states "`@statement` *Is a Unicode string that contains a Transact-SQL statement or batch.*". I made the change and it **executed the statement**. Returning an error code to a client is another question part. Initially, I wanted to return this code to Azure Data Factory but was testing in Azure Data Studio and not getting feedback in the results window. I could reference `ERROR_NUMBER()` etc .. and send those back.